# Robolectric fails to load properly when launching single test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have an Android application that I test using `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`. When I run all tests together in Android Studio, it works. But when I run a test or test class separately, I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Robolectric does not support API level 1.
```

Note that both the minimum and target API levels are specified in the manifest file. It seems that the environment is not setup properly. Adding `@Config(emulateSdk=23)` makes the test start but the test fails while accessing resources.

Any idea of what could cause the test environment not to load properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your gradle and your class :

Gradle :

```
 testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
```

In your test Class :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 25)
public class YourTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception {
       //put your test here for example
    }
)
```

**YourTest class should be put in Test folder (not AndroidTest folder)**

On Android Studio :

- Edit Configurations
- In Junit, you have to change the working directory to $MODULE_DIR$.
  The important thing is $MODULE_DIR$.

Comment: Changing the directory manually to $MODULE_DIR$ did the trick, thanks! Wonder however why I should have to do this manually for every test configuration, can't it be inferred by the IDE?

Comment: Note, as of Android Studio 4.1.2, $MODULE_DIR$ has been replaced with $ContentRoot$